# How can I use bluebird-q in browser without browserify?

Tags: javascript, browser, promise, q, bluebird

I would like to use bluebird-q (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird-q) as shim for Q in browser JS application. This is not possible out of the box as the bluebird-q library code starts with 2 NodeJS style requires:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird/js/main/promise")();
var scheduler = require("bluebird/js/main/schedule");
```

These 2 requires cannot be replaced by require of whole library (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/tree/v2.10.2#for-library-authors):

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
```

Browserify solves the problem, but this solution is not convenient enough in my opinion: it requires build step, makes the code less readable, some static code scanners do not work as expected with browserified code and most important bluebird and bluebird-q cannot be referenced as separate script files.

Two questions about this topic:

1) What is the reason whole bluebird library cannot be included into bluebird-q as is?

2) Is there more elegant solution to use bluebird-q in browser without browserify?

P.S.: I know that bluebird itself is built for browsers using browserify: this build is properly tested. There is no official browserify build of bluebird-q.

Comment: Why would you want to use bluebird-q and not bluebird's own API anyway?

Comment: There is some existing code which relies on Q APIs which cannot be refactored at the moment.

Comment: Browserify _once_ and then include that code elsewhere.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, the question is about more elegant solution which would not make use of browserify.

Comment: You only have to browserify once then save the result as a script tag

Comment: I have to run browserify on bluebird-q each time I update version of bluebird, this is possible solution, I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now browser version of the library is attached to the npm package. It can be found here: https://unpkg.com/bluebird-q@2.1.1/q.js.